# Hashing raw bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, hash, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to write a function that takes two types `T`, `U` such that `sizeof(T)+sizeof(U)<=8` and gets a `uint64_t` by just reinterpreting their bytes one after the other. However this does not seem to work. I am certain there is a quicker and more elegant (and correct) way to do it but I have no clue. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto hash8(T x, U y) {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) + sizeof(U) <= 8);

  uint64_t u = 0;
  uint64_t v = 0;
  auto px = (uint8_t*)&x;
  auto py = (uint8_t*)&y;
  for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
    u |= (uint64_t)px[i];
    u <<= 8;
  }
  for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(U); ++i) {
    v |= (uint64_t)py[i];
    v <<= 8;
  }

  return u << (sizeof(U) * 8) | v;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << hash8(131, 0) << '\n';
  std::cout << hash8(132, 0) << '\n';
  std::cout << hash8(500, 0) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "However this does not seem to work." ? Do you have a test that fails? Do you get unexpected output? Are there compiler errors?

Comment: What types are `T` & `U` supposed to be? Because if they are, or contain numbers (especially floating types), you may have portability issues to deal with. Also, if they are non "plain old data" types (ie if they contain `std::strings` or somesuch) then there are other problems.

Comment: Note that using this as hash has some limitations even for trivial types, since multiple object representations may represent the same value.

Comment: btw you say `sizeof(T)+sizeof(U)=8` but the code asserts `<= 8`

Comment: Yea sorry <= 8 is the correct one, T and U can be any types, as long as they are represented by less than 8 bytes (total). I am calling this function like this (int32_t >=0, -1) and for some reason I get the same hash for different value of the first int32_t (keeping the second at -1).

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71079245/edit) the question to add a [mcve]

Comment: Added. The first 2 both hash to 0.

Comment: Swap lines `u |= (uint64_t)px[i];` and `u <<= 8;`, likewise for `v`.

Comment: My advice: step through this with a debugger, line by line, check the value of every variable as you step through the code by doing the calculations by hand to see if it matches with what you'd expect. Fix any code that doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Also, `u << (sizeof(U) * 8)` should be `u << (sizeof(V) * 8)`.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks. I was pushing u too much on the left!

Comment: By the way, is not there a better or quicker way to achieve something like this?

Comment: `memcpy` might be faster, though an aggresive optimizer might realize that its doing the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help with the problem in your code due to lack of details, but I can propose a perhaps simpler solution.

Firstly, I recommend adding a check that the argument objects have unique object representation. Unless that is satisfied, the hash would be meaningless.

Secondly, `std::memcpy` might make this simpler:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto
hash8(T x, U y) noexcept {
    static_assert(sizeof x + sizeof y <= sizeof(std::uint64_t));
    static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>);
    static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<U>);
    std::uint64_t ret{};
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&ret);
    std::memcpy(ptr, std::addressof(x), sizeof x);
    ptr += sizeof x;
    std::memcpy(ptr, std::addressof(y), sizeof y);
    return ret;
}
```

Next, we can generalise this to arbitrary number of arguments (so long as they fit), and different return types:

```
template <typename R = std::uint64_t, typename... Args>
auto
hash(Args... args) noexcept {
    static_assert((sizeof args + ...) <= sizeof(R));
    static_assert((std::has_unique_object_representations_v<Args> && ...));
    static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<R>);
    R ret{};
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&ret);
    (
        (
            std::memcpy(ptr, std::addressof(args), sizeof args),
            ptr += sizeof args
        ), ...
    );
    return ret;
}
```

---

There is a caveat that a hash such as this is not the same across different systems, even if the sizes of the objects match.

P.S. It's pointless to make your function constexpr because you use reinterpret casting which isn't allowed in constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is usually to do a `memcpy`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring> // for memcpy

template <typename T, typename U>
auto hash8(T x, U y) {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) + sizeof(U) <= 8);

  uint64_t u = 0;
  char* u_ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&u);
  std::memcpy(u_ptr, &x, sizeof x);
  std::memcpy(u_ptr+sizeof x, &y, sizeof y);
  return u;
}
```

Any decent compiler will inline the `memcpy` call to a few bit operations, if the size parameter is known at compile time (and reasonably small).

If you actually need a `constexpr` function you can try using `std::bit_cast` from C++20 (maybe difficult if either input parameter does not have a size of 1, 2, 4, or 8).